# Provider of hyperspectral imagery SWIR band

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery, aerial-photography, europe

I'm looking for aerial hyperspectral imaging with SWIR band; size of ground pixel should not exceed 5m and dated not earlier as 2015.
Could you propose provider such of data ? Area of interest is middle of the Europe.

Comment: Not sure if there is many OS data sources for HSI in Europe, I know HYRESSA has made a big push for it, you can check out their site http://www.hyressa.net/

Answer (score 1):

We've been trialing data from the Worldview 3 platform from Digital Globe, not 'aerial' obviously, but the SWIR bands are a good spec. 8 bands between 1195nm and 2365nm at 3.7m  NADIR. It's a commercial platform, which might be your only option at your spatial resolution and age. Datasheet here: https://dg-cms-uploads-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/95/DG_WorldView3_DS_forWeb_0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Airborne hyperspectral data for small study sites in Europe can be downloaded through EUFAR. You can search for flights using: http://flight-finder.ceda.ac.uk/ or browse projects using http://browse.ceda.ac.uk/browse/badc/eufar/docs/00eufararchivecontents.html. These are free to access after registration.

Projects flown by ARSF (now NERC-ARF) use a Specim Hawk (before 2014) or Specim Fenix (2014 onwards) instrument to cover the SWIR range.